# Regex: C++ extract text within double quotes

Tags: c++

I want to extract only those words within double quotes. So, if the content is:

```
Would "you" like to have responses to your "questions" sent to you via email?
```

The answer must be

1- you
2- questions

Comment: Do you have to use regex? It's pretty simple to implement without

Comment: A simple regex to capture anything in quotes would be `\"\w+\"`, though this is doable without it.

Comment: yes i test a lot of patterns but all of them were wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string str("test \"me too\" and \"I\" did it");
std::regex rgx("\"([^\"]*)\""); // will capture "me too"
std::regex_iterator current(str.begin(), str.end(), rgx);
std::regex_iterator end;
while (current != end)
    std::cout << *current++;
```

Comment: @user522745 - right. Thanks. Fixed. (I always leave out that `*` the first time I write a regular expression like this one)

Comment: Very interesting, however how would you match something like var ABC = "" ? I tried many examples, but none seem to fit...

Comment: Why it can only run std::cout << current->str(); current++; instead of std::cout << *current++; on my test?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use Regex, you can do it like so:

```
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = R"d(Would "you" like to have responses to your "questions" sent to you via email?)d";
    std::regex rgx(R"(\"(\w+)\")");
    std::smatch match;
    std::string buffer;
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    //Split by whitespaces..
    while(ss >> buffer) 
        strings.push_back(buffer);
    for(auto& i : strings) {
        if(std::regex_match(i,match, rgx)) {
            std::ssub_match submatch = match[1];
            std::cout << submatch.str() << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

I think only MSVC and Clang supposedly support  though, otherwise you can use [boost.regex like so](http://liveworkspace.org/code/uT6rz%242).

Comment: @H2CO3 Nope. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Rapptz - POSIX has regular expressions with a C interface.

Comment: @H2CO3 - C++ has regular expressions, starting with TR1, and now mainstreamed in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split()` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c/236803#236803) then extract odd-numbered items:

```
std::vector<std::string> itms = split("would \"you\" like \"questions\"?", '"');
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = itms.begin() + 1; it != itms.end(); it += 2) {
    std::cout << *it << endl;
}
```